# 日本語に違和感: 「？」が半角英数になっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

サイト内の表記に「？」が至るところに出てきていますが、半角の「?」になっているようです。日本語サイトの場合には全角の「？」の方が良いと思います。

Comment: https://ja.traducir.win で半角のクエスチョンマークが無くなったことが確認できたので、タグを [完了] に付け替えました。

Comment: ja.traducir.win の管理外で、個別に翻訳をしているいくつかのヘルプページでは半角の `!?` が残ったままです。 例: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: あれ、ヘルプページの半角は以前直してもらったと勘違いしていました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: ひとまずヘルプページのタイトルの半角を直しました。残りはもう少しお待ちくださいませ 。

Comment: 本文の `!?`を全角に変更完了です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

翻訳者に頼む時、これも合わせて頼みます。